# Haskell: Desugar List comprehension

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

How do I desugar

```
λ: [[b|(a,b)<-[(1,"A"),(2,"B")], mod x 2 == 0]|x <- [1..10]]
[[],["A","B"],[],["A","B"],[],["A","B"],[],["A","B"],[],["A","B"]]
```

I have tried

```
do 
  x <- [1..10]
  do 
    (a,b) <- [(1,"A"),(2,"B")]
    guard $ mod x 2 == 0
    return b
```

but this seems to automatically `join` the result.

`["A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B"]`

Comment: You miss a `return` before the `do`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that nested `do` constructs "collapse":

```
do
 A
 do B
    C
```

is the same as

```
do
 A
 B
 C
```

(Or more precisely, multi-line `do` constructs desugar to nested `do` constructs.) So you want the sublist to be constructed and add to the outer list, rather than building a single list using the nested `do` construct to fill it.

Using a hybrid, intermediate approach, you build the outer list by `return`ing each inner list separately.

```
do
  x <- [1..10]
  return [[b|(a,b)<-[(1,"A"),(2,"B")], mod x 2 == 0]
```

Then you desugar *that* comprehension:

```
do
  x <- [1..10]
  return (do
      (a, b) <- ...
      guard $ mod x 2 == 0
      return b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you return the list comprehension, you need an **extra `return`**:

```
do 
  x <- [1..10]
  return $ do 
    (a,b) <- [(1,"A"),(2,"B")]
    guard $ mod x 2 == 0
    return b
```

Otherwise, you would construct have constructed it like:

```
[b|x <- [1..10], (a,b)<-[(1,"A"),(2,"B")], mod x 2 == 0]
```

Since you used the `do` as tailing element in the outer `do`, that `do` was redundant.

Answer (score 0):

I made minor modifications to your original list comprehension.

```
[ (x,[(b) | (a,b) <- [(1,"A"),(2,"B")], mod x 2 == 0]) | x <- [1..10] ]
```

Which resulted in

```
[(1,[]),(2,["A","B"]),(3,[]),(4,["A","B"]),(5,[]),(6,["A","B"]),(7,[]),(8,["A","B"]),(9,[]),(10,["A","B"])]
```

So with these parameters, it was producing b of (a,b) or a [].

This translated into the following map.

```
map (\x -> if mod x 2 == 0 then [x] else [] ) [1..10]
```

Which produced

```
[[],[2],[],[4],[],[6],[],[8],[],[10]]
```

The following segment of your list comprehension

```
[b|(a,b)<-[(1,"A"),(2,"B")]]
```

Produces simply

```
["A","B"]
```

The following map produces the same.

```
map snd [(1,"A"),(2,"B")]
```

Replacing [x] in the first map with the preceding map

```
map (\x -> if mod x 2 == 0 then map snd [(1,"A"),(2,"B")] else [] ) [1..10]
```

Does exactly what your list comprehension does. Changing the parameters would result in identical results.